# Contour Plot of complex roots of dispersion equation

Tags: plotting

I want a contour plot of the complex roots of the following fifth degree dispersion equation in wave velocity `v` in Mathematica:

```
[1+(c2^2/c1^2) v^2][1+k t1 c2 v+(c2 d/ k) v(1+ k t2 c2 v+(1/2) k^2 t2^2 c2^2 v^2)]+(e c2 d/ k) v[1+k t2 c2 v+(1/2) k^2 t2^2 c2^2 v^2] = 0;
```

The parameters are given as:

```
c1=4631.0; c2=2280.1; d=8066.8; e=0.0168; t1=0.1; t2=0.1; k=1;
```

Please someone help me. I am learning Mathematica but I need the above help for my research work.

Comment: Initialize the parameters first.  Then  correct your expression:  Change brackets to parentheses.  Brackets are used for functions and arrays in Mathematica, next, simpler to remove the =0, then  just assign your expresson to a name such as `theFuntion=`.   So will have `theFuntion=expression here`.  Then finally use `NSolve` as in `theRoots=v/.NSolve[theFunction==0,v]` to obtain the roots.  Don't know what you mean abut contour plot of the complex roots though.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Here v is complex in general. I want Contour plot of complex roots v.

Comment: @Nantu:  Suggest you make the changes I suggested, run the code in a notebook and post both the code and roots back into your thread  by copy/paste into your post then highlight the code and select {} in the menu above the edit window to format it as code then better explain what you wish to do with them.

Comment: Do you mean plot $v(k)$ or just to show 5 roots at `k=1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers your other question that was deleted as a duplicate of this one.

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = (1 + (c2^2/c1^2)*v^2)*(1 + 
       k*t1*c2*v + (c2*d/k)*v*(1 + k*t2*c2*v + (1/2)*k^2*t2^2*c2^2*v^2)) + (e*
       c2*d/k)*v*(1 + k*t2*c2*v + (1/2)*k^2*t2^2*c2^2*v^2) == 0;

c1 = 4631;
c2 = 22801/10;
d = 80668/10;
e = 168*10^-4;
k = 1;

roots = Solve[eqn, v];

n = Length@roots;
```

**EDIT:**

Using [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  Evaluate[func[v /. roots[[k]]]],
  {t1, 10^-10, 10^-1}, {t2, 10^-10, 10^-1},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t1, t2, func}),
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None},
  PlotRange -> All,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  MaxRecursion -> 5],
 {{func, Re}, {Re, Im, Abs},
  ControlType -> RadioButtonBar},
 {{k, 1, "root"}, Range[n],
  ControlType -> RadioButtonBar},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {func, k}]
```

[image]

With manual scaling

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  Evaluate[func[v /. roots[[k]] /.
     {t1 -> 10^logt1, t2 -> 10^logt2}]],
  {logt1, -10, -1}, {logt2, -10, -1},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
     {Log[t1], Log[t2], func}),
  PlotRange -> All,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  MaxRecursion -> 5],
 {{func, Re}, {Re, Im, Abs},
  ControlType -> RadioButtonBar},
 {{k, 1, "root"}, Range[n],
  ControlType -> RadioButtonBar},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {func, k}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice answer (+1}.

Comment: Dear Bob Hanlon, Sir thank you very much for your code. It works on my PC but have some problem for different t1 and t2. I need another help from you sir - Actually, according to my model, the ranges of t1 and t2 are [10^-10, 10^-1]. I want to plot the real and imaginary parts of each root on the logarithmic scales of t1 and t2 and indicate log(t1), log(t2) and Re/Im parts of the particular root along the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis, respectively in the 3D plot. It is my kind request to you please help me sir.

Comment: @BobHanlon: Sir, thank you very much for your kind help. The real part of any one of the roots should be like this posted in the link https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291185/plot-with-marked-extremum-and-saddle-point-if-any-in-wave-velocity-as-a-function     I can't get exact figure! But i must appreciate your effort in helping me. If please go through the link pasted above once if possible!

Comment: The target plot has the axes reversed and the plot range restricted (`Automatic` vs `All`).

Answer (score 4):

There are 5 roots `v=x+Iy` which could be defined as follows

```
c1 = 4631.0; c2 = 2280.1; d = 8066.8; e = 0.0168; t1 = 0.1; t2 = 0.1; k = 1;

 f = (1 + (c2^2/c1^2) v^2) (1 + 
       k t1 c2 v + (c2 d/k) v (1 + 
          k t2 c2 v + (1/2) k^2 t2^2 c2^2 v^2)) + (e c2 d/k) v (1 + 
       k t2 c2 v + (1/2) k^2 t2^2 c2^2 v^2) /. v -> x + I y;
r1 = FindRoot[{Re[f] == 0, Im[f] == 0}, {x, .1}, {y, .1}]

{x -> -5.34699*10^-8, y -> 4.12598*10^-26}

r2 = FindRoot[{Re[f] == 0, Im[f] == 0}, {x, -.1}, {y, -.1}]

{x -> -0.00438575, y -> -0.0043858}

r3 = FindRoot[{Re[f] == 0, Im[f] == 0}, {x, -.1}, {y, .1}]

{x -> -0.00438575, y -> 0.0043858}
 r4 = 
 FindRoot[{Re[f] == 0, Im[f] == 0}, {x, 1/10}, {y, -3}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 4]

{x -> -4.12454*10^-15, y -> -2.04804}

r5 = 
 FindRoot[{Re[f] == 0, Im[f] == 0}, {x, 1/10}, {y, 3}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 4]

{x -> -4.12437*10^-15, y -> 2.04804}
```

Visualization

```
Show[ContourPlot[{Re[f] == 0, Im[f] == 0}, {x, -1/50, 
   1/50}, {y, -1/50, 1/50}], 
 Graphics[{{Red, PointSize[.015], Point[{x, y}] /. r1}, {Red, 
    PointSize[.015], Point[{x, y}] /. r2}, {Red, PointSize[.015], 
    Point[{x, y}] /. r3}}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
Show[ContourPlot[{Re[f] == 0, Im[f] == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], 
 Graphics[{{Red, PointSize[.015], Point[{x, y}] /. r4}, {Red, 
    PointSize[.015], Point[{x, y}] /. r5}}]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

If `v` depends on `t1, t2` then see answer @Bob Hanlon.

Comment: Sir thank you very much for your code. It works nice on PC. I need another help from you sir - As you told me in your previous comment, is it possible to contour/density plot of the five roots v(k) as a function of k? Range of k is (0,1]. If possible, how to indicate the extrema of v(k) with mentioning max/min of v and the corresponding point? If so, please help me.

Comment: Do you mean max/min `Abs[v[k]]`?

Comment: Sir, I actually mean max/min of Re[v[k]] and Im[v[k]] assuming v is dependent on k as you suggested. I think it would be a nice idea to show where the wave velocity and attenuation attain max/min  in density plot. Please help sir.

Comment: @NantuSarkar in general, it is better to ask these separate & new questions as separate & new questions. You can do this by making new question posts that link to this one, rather than by making additional requests within the comments of answers to your questions.

Comment: @NantuSarkar Could you please start a new topic with your requests?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sir, I have posted one new request related to the above separately following your suggestion in the: link https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291185/plot-with-marked-extremum-and-saddle-point-if-any-in-wave-velocity-as-a-function         Could you please help?