# Dispersion equation

Tags: plotting

I want surface plot of real part of any one of the complex roots of the following fifth degree dispersion equation in wave velocity v in Mathematica. Surface plot of real part of any complex root w.r.t t1 and t2:

```
(1+(c2^2/c1^2)*v^2)*(1+k*t1*c2*v+(c2*d/k)*v*(1+k*t2*c2*v+(1/2)*k^2*t2^2*c2^2*v^2))+(e*c2*d/k)*v*(1+k*t2*c2*v+(1/2)*k^2*t2^2*c2^2*v^2)==0;
```

The parameters are given as:

```
c1=4631.0; c2=2280.1; d=8066.8; e=0.0168; k=1;
```

For surface plot, ranges of t1 and t2 may be taken as -10 to -1 for each.

Please someone help me. I am learning Mathematica but I need the above help for my research work.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. `[` and `]` are used for passing parameters to a function. Can you please use correct Mathematica syntax or include  $\LaTeX$ form to facilitate disambiguation?

Comment: Please consider deleting your duplicate question at [Contour Plot of complex roots of dispersion equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/291068).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick attempt at a solution for the above problem.  The script solves the equation for each pair of t1 and t2 for a real solution.

```
Clear["`*"];
c1 = 4631.0; c2 = 2280.1; d = 8066.8; e = 0.0168; k = 1;
data = Values[Table[Solve[(1 + (c2^2/c1^2)*v^2)*(k*t1*c2*v + (c2*d/k)*
      v*(1 + k*t2*c2*v + (1/2)*k^2*t2^2*c2^2*v^2)) + (e*c2*d/k)*
   v*(1 + k*t2*c2*v + (1/2)*k^2*t2^2*c2^2*v^2) == 0, v, 
Reals], {t1, -1, 10}, {t2, -1, 10}]]
ListPlot3D[data[[All, All, 1, 1]]]
```

[image]